# Recoreding the screen as seen by the user with Zoom enabled

Tags: macos, screen-capture, zoom

Because of my impairment, I usually use the Zoom feature built into OS X, and I'm giving a presentation in which I'd like to show a video of how I use the web. To do so, I'd like to make a screen recording that shows the screen as seen with zoom enabled. Is there a way to do this, preferably with QuickTime or ScreenFlow?

Comment: You mean the zoom feature with ctrl+mwheel? My screenflow records the screen as I see it, with zoom. Does it not for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Could it be because I hae an old version of screenflow? 2.1.9

Comment: I guess so, I'm using 4.5 which I thought is old :D